# lista no se guarda en clase

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Estoy haciendo un programa donde se me pide que se guarden ciertos valores en una lista de una clase.

El problema es que cuando voy entrando valores, no entran y no encuentro el error. Cuando entras en la opción dos, metes las variables que te pide (codi,data,...), pero una vez vuelven a la función `creaVol` no se guardan en la lista.

```
class Vol:
    def __init__(self, codi = None, data = None, companyia = None, tipus_avio = None, desti = None):
        self.codi = codi
        self.data = data
        self.companyia = companyia
        self.avio = tipus_avio
        self.desti = desti
        self.llistaVols = []

    def __str__(self):
       r1 = str(self.codi) + " - " + str(self.data) + " - " + str(self.companyia) + " - " + str(self.avio) + " - " + str(self.desti)
       return r1

    def llista_Vols(self,vol):
        self.llistaVols.append([vol])



def comprovaCodiVol(codi):
    r = (2<len(codi)<8) and (codi[0:2].isalpha() or codi[0:3].isalpha()) and (codi[2:].isdigit() or codi[3:].isdigit())
    return (r)


class Data:
    def __init__(self,dia,mes,any):
        self.dia = dia
        self.mes = mes
        self.any = any

    def __str__(self):
       r2 = str(self.dia)+"/"+str(self.mes)+"/"+str(self.any)
       return r2

    def datallista(self):
        list += [self.dia,self.mes,self.any]
        return list

def comprovaDia(dia,mes,any):
    if (dia == 0 or dia>31) or (mes == 2 and dia>28):
        return False
    elif any%4==0 and (any%100!=0 or any%400==0):
      if mes==2 and dia>=29 and dia<=0:
        return False
      else:
        return True
    elif ((mes==4 or mes==6 or mes==9 or mes == 11) and dia>30):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def comprovaMes(mes):
    r = (mes>=1 and int(mes)<=12)
    return r

def comprovaAny(any):
    r = (len(str(any))==4)
    return r



class Aeroport:
    def __init__(self,codi,nom,vols = []):
        self.codi = codi
        self.nom = nom
        self.vols = vols

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.codi)+"-"+str(self.nom)+"-"+str(self.vols)



def comprovaCodiAeroport(codi):
  r=(len(codi) == 3 and codi.isalpha())
  return r

def codiRepetit(aeroport, codi_nou):
  for i in aeroport.vols:
    if i.codi == codi_nou:
      return False
  return True


def executaMenu(aeroport = ""):
    if aeroport == "":
        aeroport = Aeroport("BCN", "Josep Tarradellas Barcelona-El Prat")
    trobat = False
    while trobat == False:
        opcio = menu(aeroport)
        if int(opcio)>= 0 and int(opcio)<=6:
            if int(opcio) == 0:
                trobat = True
                vol = Vol()
                print ("\nSortint del programa...")
                print(vol.llistaVols)
            elif int(opcio) == 1:
                modificadadesAerop(aeroport)
            elif int(opcio) == 2:
                creaVol(aeroport)
            elif int(opcio) == 3:
                modificaVol(aeroport)
            elif int(opcio) == 4:
                esborraVol(aeroport)
            elif int(opcio) == 5:
                cercaVol(aeroport)
            elif int(opcio) == 6:
                mostraVols(aeroport)
        else:
            print ("\nError. Cal que introduïu un número del 0 al 6\n")
            trobat = False

    return aeroport

def menu(aeroport):
    print("=== Gestió de l'areoport",aeroport.nom,"(",aeroport.codi,") ===")
    print("0. Surt del programa")
    print("1. Modifica les dades de l’aeroport")
    print("2. Crea un nou vol")
    print("3. Modifica un vol")
    print("4. Esborra un vol")
    print("5. Cerca un vol")
    print("6. Mostra tots els vols")
    opcio = input("Què voleu fer? ")
    return opcio




def creaVol(aeroport):
    print ("\nHeu escollit l'opció de crear un nou vol\n")
    vol = Vol()
    codi,data,desti,companyia,avio = dadesVol(aeroport, vol)
    print("\nVol creat amb èxit")
    print("\n",vol,"\n")
    aeroport.vols.append(vol)
    vol.llistaVols.append([codi,str(data),desti,companyia,avio])
    print (vol.llistaVols)



def dadesVol(aeroport, vol):
    codiCreat = False
    dataCreat = False
    destiCreat = False
    while codiCreat == False:
      codi = input("Introdueix codi de vol: ")
      codi = codi.upper()
      if comprovaCodiVol(codi) and codiRepetit(aeroport, codi):
        vol.codi = codi
        codiCreat = True
      else:
        print ("Codi de vol erroni")


    while dataCreat == False:
      dia = input("Introdueix el dia: ")
      mes = input("Introdueix el mes: ")
      any = input("Introdueix el any en format XXXX: ")
      if (comprovaDia(int(dia),int(mes),int(any)) and comprovaMes(int(mes)) and comprovaAny(any)):
        vol.data = Data(dia,mes,any)
        dataCreat = True
      else:
        print ("Data erronia")


    while destiCreat == False:
      desti = input("Introdueix el codi de desti: ")
      desti = desti.upper()
      if comprovaCodiAeroport(desti):
        vol.desti = desti
        destiCreat = True
      else:
        print ("Codi de destí erroni")


    vol.companyia = input("Introdueix la companyia: ")
    vol.avio = input("Introdueix el tipus d'avio: ")

    if destiCreat == True and codiCreat == True and dataCreat == True:
        return codi,vol.data,desti,vol.companyia,vol.avio


def buscarVol(aeroport):
    codi = input("\nIntrodueix-hi codi del vol: ")
    codi = codi.upper()
    if comprovaCodiVol(codi):
        f = open("vols.txt", "r+")
        x = f.readlines()
        fila = 0
        for linia in x:
            if codi in linia:
                return fila
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executaMenu()
```

Comment: hay mucho código aquí, sería bueno que proporcionaras un [mcve] con el código mínimo necesario para reproducir el error, así como el comportamiento esperado

Comment: No hablo catalán y me resulta difícil seguir la lógica del código.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes guardar los datos en la clase porque la lista no pertenece a la clase.
Las dos listas de vuelos que aparecen en tu código las estás definiendo en los métodos `__init__` de las clases `Vuelo` y `Aeropuerto`.
Cuando cualquiera de las dos instancias muera, perderás esas listas.
En particular el objeto `Vuelo` morirá cuando termine la función `creaVuelo`.
La próxima vez que llames a esta función obtendrás un nuevo objeto `Vuelo` que, al ejecutar su función `__init__` creará una lista `lista_vuelos` nueva y vacía.

Para que tu lista sea de clase la tienes que definir a la altura de la clase, no dentro de una función:

```
class Vuelo:
    lista_vuelos = []
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
```

No tengo claro que la clase `Vuelo` deba guardar una lista de todos los vuelos que existen ya que cada aeropuerto ya guarda una lista con sus propios vuelos.